# SQl query does not provide desirable result - issues with where clause

Tags: sql

I was wondering if you culd help with the following query:

```
SELECT * , 
cast(date_trunc('month', invoice_deferred_final_date) as date) date_transaction,
CASE WHEN invoice_subscription_amount_usd = total_amount and invoice_subscription_amount_usd > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as new_flag,
CASE WHEN prev_amount > 0 AND invoice_subscription_amount_usd is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as churn,
CASE WHEN invoice_subscription_amount_usd > 0 AND prev_amount is null and invoice_subscription_amount_usd != total_amount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as reactivation,
CASE WHEN invoice_subscription_amount_usd > 0 AND prev_amount > 0 and invoice_subscription_amount_usd > prev_amount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as upgrade,
CASE WHEN invoice_subscription_amount_usd > 0 AND prev_amount > 0 and invoice_subscription_amount_usd < prev_amount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as downgrade

from (

    SELECT
    *,
    sum(invoice_subscription_amount_usd) over (partition by property_buid order by invoice_deferred_final_date) total_amount,
    lag(invoice_subscription_amount_usd,1) over (partition by property_buid order by invoice_deferred_final_date) prev_amount,
    lEAD(invoice_subscription_amount_usd,1) over (partition by property_buid order by invoice_deferred_final_date) next_amount
    FROM subscription 
    ) sub 
where new_flag = 1 or churn = 1 or downgrade = 1 or upgrade = 1
```

I am getting this error but I do not know how to fix it. Thanks in advance
ERROR:  column "new_flag" does not exist
LINE 18: where new_flag = 1 or churn = 1 or downgrade = 1 or upgrade ...
^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 1198

Comment: 1) tag with database platform, 2) show all Table DDL.

Comment: I do not have access to the Table DDL... the issue is related to where I am placing the where claus, but I am unable to fix it. these new "columns" have been created in the outer query.

Comment: You can't use derived columns in the WHERE clause.